# I have moved my react-native project folder, how I reconfigure the libs path?

Tags: react-native, config, libraries, axios, jestjs

i have moved my react-native project to another folder, and i'm having trouble with axios requests (local requests are ok, but global adresses return network error) and when I was checking the libraries I noticed that the paths in package.json files are the old path, could it be related to this error? And is there any other way to reconfigure those paths than manually?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I forgot to set the AllowArbitraryLoads to true xD my bad